# how to set value of a matrix in the loop?

Tags: r

I have two matrix, same size, 2 million rows and  2 columns. 
`matrix_a` has values, while `matrix_b` is blank, the value of `matrix_b` will be decided by the vaule in `matrix_a`.

```
matrix_b <- matrix(, nrow(matrix_a),2)
for(rows in 1:nrow(matrix_a)){
    if (matrix_a[rows,1]==0){
         .....do something get values of x, 
         matrix_b[rows,2] = x
         }
    else {
          do sth else get value of y,
          then set matrix_b 
          }
    }
```

First, how can I speed up this loop, as there are 2 millions rows, it is very slow to process.
Second,  I noticed  when I tried to simply copy one value from `matrix_a` to `matrix_b`, it seems does not work. For example, while in my data

```
matrix_a[1,1] = 'user1'
```

after I copy the values as

```
matrix_b[1,1] = matrix_a[1,1]
```

however, the result turns on as

```
matrix_b[1,1]='1'
```

How come? Why the values 'user1' did not set to `matrix_b`?

I just found out this might be related to the sorting, as I sort my data first to generate `matrix_a`. The value '1' here means the first row after sorting, but I still do not know how it ends up in `matrix_b`.

Comment: It would be nice to see what should be done while `do something`.

Comment: You would get a better reply if you put something real in your code, and perhaps 5 rows of data to show what you want to happen.

Comment: You should have `} else {`as a single line.  Otherwise R will not reach the `else`.

Comment: @Henry: it's actually ok to have the `}` then a <CR> then `else {` . the important thing is that if there's no opening `{` on the same line  as `else` then the next <CR> terminates the `else`

Comment: You can save a lot of time by vectorizing. Instead of `if(matrix_a[rows,1]==0)`,  first calculate all the x values, then `matrix_b[,2]<- x*(matrix_a[,1]==0)`  .

Comment: Thanks Carl, I am a newbie, let me read about vectorizing first.

Comment: I think I found out why the matrix only copy "1" instead the real value  into matrix b..   The reason is, I sort matrix a on two column first.  the value "1" means it is first row after sorting, that is where this "1" come from.... However, I still do not understand, even after this,  matrix_a[1,1] does have real value, which is 'user1', but how come matrix_b only have the sorted rownumber?

Comment: Please take note of the code formatting tools available when writing questions.

Comment: You could also use the compiler in R 2.14.0 to byte-compile your code.

Answer (score 2):

If the two "somethings" and "somethings-else" can be encapsulated into functions that deliver a vector of the same length as `matrix_a[ ,1]`, you could construct the vectors, `sth_a` and `sth_b` and then run

```
matrix_b[ , 2] <- ifelse(matrix_a[ ,1] == 0,  sth_a , sth_b)
```